# how to overlap two images and make a cross line between the two using either HTML or CSS or JS like the below example

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, uiimageview

how to overlap two images and make a cross line between the two using either HTML or CSS or JS like the below example, you can see a line between the 2 images. I am trying to create a similar HTML document using 2 images but unable to do that. 
[This is the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/medUG.jpg)

Here is a webpage similar to which I am trying to develop a page using 2 images.
https://www.avidiabank.com/

Comment: I just checked out the page's code. This is not a multiple image. It's a javascript that detects hover on the left or right sides, then it changes the background image of the body to one with a black and white version on the desired side.

Comment: CCS Masks can be used for that kind of effect. But not all browsers support this feature, currently. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet responsible for producing this effect.

```
  if ($('.section-splash-page').length) {
      $('.splash-btn-personal')
       .hover(function () {
         $('.section-splash-page').addClass('hover-left'); })
       .mouseleave(function () {
          $('.section-splash-page').removeClass('hover-left');
       });

 $('.splash-btn-business')
     .hover(function () {
      $('.section-splash-page').addClass('hover-right');
     })
     .mouseleave(function () {
                $('.section-splash-page').removeClass('hover-right');
            });
        }
```

Below is a CSS part of this

```
.section-splash-page.hover-right {
    background-image: url(/sites/all/themes/avidia/assets/img/splash_page-right.jpg);
}
.section-splash-page.hover-left {
    background-image: url(/sites/all/themes/avidia/assets/img/splash_page- left.jpg); 
}

.section-splash-page {
    background-image: url(/sites/all/themes/avidia/assets/img/splash_page.jpg),url(/sites/all/themes/avidia/assets/img/splash_page-left.jpg),url(/sites/all/themes/avidia/assets/img/splash_page-right.jpg);
    background-size: cover,0,0;
    background-position: center center,center center,center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat,no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps you understand the effect.